# Is there any way to send mails in nodejs server without using any external modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid, nodemailer, mail-server

Basically, we can use nodemailer like npm-modules for our purpose to send emails in nodejs.
But I am actually wanting to develop my own nodemailer, so how can I actually proceed.

Please guide me.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please share your code or tell me more details.

Comment: Take a look at the nodemailer source code and see how it's done?